# comment reply system in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to make a comment reply system in swift.Single comment have multiple replies.This is single level comment system.

Can we make this using UITableView or we need to use UIScrollView. Can you please give some suggestion and if there is any sample code that would be big help, as I search lot on google but not found anything suitable. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use TableView for this.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister for the reply. How can we move the cell to right to show reply?

Comment: have two cells defined. one left and one right. you dont 'move' it. just determine which one to show

Comment: @Scriptable: Do you have any example code?

Comment: I dont have any sorry, Just create a cell for standard comments and one for replies that puts the text to the right

Comment: have you get any solution. i am also have same issue?

Answer (score 1):

There can be two approaches based on how you want to use the tableview

Lets assume you are having a comment object, with array of replies

**1.) Using Two different cells**

-> For each comment you can use the layout as shown in your screenshot, in which the image is starting from the left most, followed by the name and text or share material.

Each Reply will then be shown using another cell which will be having the leading margin such that, the image of person replied, starts from the same position of where name of person who commented is starting.

For this you will need to convert your Comment object and its inner reply array into a 1D array, with proper types / cell-identifiers

**2.) Using Custom Header and Cells**

-> Here also the layout of both will be same as explained above, the only thing that will change is instead of making the comment object as 1D, you can use comment object to populate Section Headers, while replies can be used to populate the replies.

Comment: Actually I have tried this approach but with this approch I am not able to set the layout correctly. Height of cell is not set correctly.

Comment: Try to dynamically change heightLayoutConstraint on the basis of calculated height of your text and other views.

Comment: Do you guys happen to have a git with a working solution, as I'd like to take a look?